# Azure App Service shared hosting breaking container startup

Tags: azure, docker, kudu, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-appservice

I have an Azure App Service running my own docker image based on `node:14-alpine`.

Deploying to the service works and the website runs as expected.

I want to be able to share a few files between the containers, I had previously been using an Azure FileStorage account mapped as a docker volume, this worked however for some reason docker/pm2/node would constantly perform writes meaning a massive cost.

I wanted to use the in-built persisted storage and set the application setting `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE` to true, in theory this should share the `/home` directory between containers and enable storage to persist reboots.

However after changing this setting and restarting, the container no longer starts successfully and gives no reason why.

The logs I get are below:

```
docker run -d -p 2641:3001 --name [service_name]_2_d9625e76 -e PORT=3001 -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=true -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=[service_name] -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=[service_name].azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=962880a44b3c94xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1e1a66c48ac6b9 -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 [service_name].azurecr.io/[service_name]:latest

2021-04-06T17:47:14.867Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container [service_name]_2_d9625e76 for site [service_name]
2021-04-06T17:47:30.612Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container [service_name]_2_d9625e76. Elapsed time = 15.7444228 sec
... lots of lines
2021-04-06T17:56:52.574Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container [service_name]_2_d9625e76. Elapsed time = 577.707016 sec
2021-04-06T17:57:14.909Z ERROR - Container [service_name]_2_d9625e76 for site [service_name] did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 600.041979 sec
2021-04-06T17:57:14.916Z ERROR - Container [service_name]_2_d9625e76 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 3001, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
```

I can't find any more logs to check or any reason it would fail.

What is `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE` breaking about my container?
I have bash access to the running kudu instance but I can't even find the node website modules.

Are there any logs that would allow me to view what is failing or anything I've not considered with the `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE` setting?

Comment: How do you deploy the image to Azure App Service? The docker-compose file or just in the Azure portal?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the container wait time to max by setting WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT = 1800?

Comment: @CharlesXu I use a Dockerfile to build the container, this is pushed to an Azure Container Registry which uses a webhook to trigger a deployment in the App Service

Comment: I mean the first deployment, do you create the app service in the Azure portal with a docker-compose file? or use the command?

Comment: @CharlesXu I created the app using the portal but not a docker compose file, I used "Single container" and selected the image from the container registry

Comment: @JasonPan I've set this to 600 then 1800 and it still fails to start within this time. Turning off the `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE ` setting, the container starts in approx 15 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, enable persistent storage by setting the environment variable `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE` as `true` does not affect the container operation. It only means you can use persistent storage or not.

Second, if you set the environment variable `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE` as `true`, then you also need to configure the mount path. Up to now, as I know it only can be configured in the docker-compose file. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-multi-container-app#add-persistent-storage) is the example.

If you only want to deploy it in Azure Portal with a single container. Then I recommend you use the storage account. In this way, you only need to configure the mapping in the settings. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?pivots=container-linux) are the steps.

Comment: I see, so this needs to use something like `volumes:
${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/site/wwwroot:/var/www/html
`? Also I tried using a storage account first but something about the setup is causing 1.4m "hot grs write" operations per month, I have a support case open about that

Comment: @bendataclear Yes, you need to set the volume like `volumes: ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/site/wwwroot:/var/www/html`. But you can change the mount path as you need.

Comment: Went through a few iterations of errors but eventually it worked using the command `volumes: - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}:/data`, appreciated

Comment: not working for me , i use a single container

Comment: @QuentinMerlin Then you can only mount the Azure File Share in the portal.

Comment: I already use docker compose , but the container fail to start

Comment: @QuentinMerlin Create a new question with more details. I can't give the solution without any details.

Comment: yes : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68029950/azure-app-service-shared-hosting-fail-container-startup